# Reading JEDEC ID from user space

Tags: linux, driver, firmware, flash-memory

Is there a way to read JEDEC ID for a given NAND/NOR flash device from user space?
   What would be the best way to implement this functionality if it is not there?

Thanks,

Quyen

Comment: Consider asking at : **https://electronics.stackexchange.com/** since Stackoverflow is for asking programming questions.

Answer (score 0):

You can dump the flash memory to know the `JEDEC ID`. Use `MTD` user space commands to read flash memory or try this. https://www.silabs.com/community/blog.entry.html/2016/01/26/chapter_9_2_storel-hZDb